# Grep Json String for logstash filter

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I am new to logstash and trying to go through different blogs / links to understand it in detail. I am stuck with a issue where I want to parse Json string which is embedded in a normal string line .

Input String

> 2017-01-27 11:54:48 INFO PropertiesReader:33 -
>   **{"timestamp":1485518878968,"h":"297268184dde", "l":"INFO", "cN":"org.com.logstash.demo", "mN":"loadProperties", "m":"load
>   property file  from /var/tmp/conf"}**

I want to extract highlighted Json string and apply Json plug-in on the Json . How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Please show your current logstash config

Comment: It is very basic at the moment. Json string is part of greddy data.filter {grok {  match => [ "message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:LogDate} %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} %{WORD:threadName}:%{NUMBER:ThreadID}%{GREEDYDATA:Line}" ] }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to use the `json` filter after your `grok` filter:

```
filter {
    grok { 
         match => [ "message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:LogDate} %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} %{WORD:threadName}:%{NUMBER:ThreadID} - %{GREEDYDATA:Line}" ] 
    }
    json {
        source => "Line"
    }
}
```

Also note that I've modified your grok pattern a little bit to exclude the `-` before the JSON data.

Comment: Great. It worked and can see the output. Thanks for your help @Val.

Comment: Now I am stuck with another issue where I am passing stack trace as json. Length of strack trace is quite big ( > 5k Character ). Though it is a valid Json , in logstash it is failing  with  `exception=>#<LogStash::Json::ParserError: Unexpected end-of-input in VALUE_STRING` error. Is there any size constraint in Json plugin ? As when I am reducing the size of strack trace, Json plugin is working without issue.